# Where is our demarcation line between Space Exploration and Physics?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are quite a number of question topics that could fit on either. Do we have thoughts on what will make a question better fit here or on Physics?

If it asks for mathematics, does that make it a physics question? Does it have to refer to actually using those equations to navigate/calculate thrust to be on-topic here?

Comment: What happens when it's space physics? My question on sound in space is considered off topic but a question on if artificial gravity in space is possible is not?

Comment: Sound in space feels more physics - it has nothing to do with exploration. And in fact there is a question on physics on this exact topic.

Comment: Would the question "Could two astronauts in space walk communicate between each other without transmitters?" be a valid question.

Comment: It still isn't exploration - so to me it feels off topic.

Answer (score 14):

The border is incredibly soft.

The more diverse SE sites exist, the more complicated it becomes to put a question into a specific category. Was it ever considered at SE to implement "cross-posts" in any way? Let's say, a question is asked here in space exploration, but it is *listed* by the author in e.g. astronomy and physics too? From my point of view, eventually this is going to make a lot of sense. (I somehow imagine special tags for cross-posting.)

Answer (score 8):

The border is soft, but here's where I draw the line.

If it is about spacecraft operations, or engineering, it belongs here.

If it is a very general physics question, then it could best go there.

Some questions could fit in to either category (How does an Ion Engine work).

Space Exploration

- How much fuel do I need to get to go to *_*_?

Physics

- What is the source of the 11 year solar cycle?

Either site

- What is the optimal transfer orbit?
- How does an Ion Engine work?

Comment: I'd say the ion engine example would go to Physics.

Comment: @Undo: It's an engineering and a science question, don't see why it couldn't go to either. In fact, I'd say it's probably more on topic here...

Comment: ...especially that Physics.SE got a very strong 'theoretical physics' slant and doesn't like questions that lean on engineering. Especially if you want hard numbers in the answer, don't count on Physics.SE.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the utility of the answer is another consideration. In cases where one thinks that a good answer could be found to be helpful, useful, or instructive to readers coming to the site for on-topic learning in the future, then try to refrain from reflexively reaching for the insta-close button.

If for example the question is about astronauts [shooting at the Sun](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26276/12102), and several well-received answers with instructive insight on principles of astrodynamics and orbital mechanics appear quickly, then perhaps refraining from reflexive insta-closeing was the right course of action.

Alternatives, especially in low to moderate question-rate sites include helpful comments or possibly in some cases proactive edits, with discretion of course.

Comment: While I get what you are saying, the general guidance is not to keep a question that would otherwise be migrated just because it has answers which are on-topic. This is because visitors search on questions, not answers. A good answer does not usually save a bad question.

Comment: If the answers are on-topic, then it's more worth to edit the question on-topic. Off-topic questions must be closed or migrated due to what @RoryAlsop said.

Comment: @derwodamaso sometimes the true nature of the question, (including its on-or-off-topicness) evolves as answers are worked out. Pre-closing before letting others explore the implications of the question by answering can kill a question, as the closing prevents people from answering and looking at each others' answers. Off-topic-ness is not a simple, self-evident boolean, sometimes it takes a bit of time and people working together to come to a consensus. Drive-by close-voters can block this also. Communicating via comments is not the same as reading others' answers and then commenting on those.

Comment: In a medium to low question rate site this kind of collaboration happens all the time. In these cases the quick-closers lower the effectiveness of the community effort.

Comment: Regarding editing questions to fit answers, please see @Gilles answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89373/154443 as well as other posts on Chameleon Questions on meta. Key line: "If all of the answers would still be ok after your edit, then yes, go ahead."

Comment: I agree with you on the point of not closing questions instantly. In this case, I did not vote for closing instantly and keep giving you upvotes ;-) Still I think the question must be edited on-topic, by someone who has time to do so ^^

Comment: @derwodamaso one can't "give upvotes" especially to me since I didn't post there. Anyway thanks for your comment!

Answer (score -1):

I would say that if it is directly related to Space Exploration, let it stay. If it is something like

> How much fuel would I need in rocket x to get to planet y?

Then it's probably on-topic here.

If, on the other hand, it's something like this:

> What makes an ion engine work?

Then it should go to Physics.